# Web Role is crashing too often

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, windows-server-2012

I have a web role which works fine when test in emulator. But for some reasons, App is crashing frequently. Crashing is random, means there is no specific code which is doing that. Same page works fine for sometime and then causes the application to crash suddently. Windows event is showing following trace for the error

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108835
```

Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16579, time stamp: 0x51637f77
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000000000001a9ea
Faulting process id: 0xfdc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cebece494746aa
Faulting application path: d:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 8e17cf44-2ac1-11e3-93f0-00155da90d91
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Any help is really appreciated.

thanx

Comment: There is mostly likely an uncaught exception which is causing your role to recycle.  Can you attach intellitrace to your deployment?

Answer (score 1):

The 0xc00000fd exception is a stack overflow exception.  You likely have an infinite or forever recursive loop, dividing by a number that's very close to 0, or some other un-handled error that's causing stack overflow.

Comment: How can I trace which part of code is causing stack overflow. As I told you, same code sometimes works fine.

Comment: asp.net web form 4.0.

Comment: If you publish from visual studio you can turn on intellitrace logging under the advanced options.  Then you can have a trace of what is causing the exception when it happens.  Or take a look at the WADLogs table(assuming you have diagnostics turned on)

Answer (score 1):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/03/31/net-case-study-stackoverflow-exception-when-using-a-complex-rowfilter.aspx for how to troubleshoot c00000fd errors in .NET.